# How to label vertices in a grid with random integers?

Tags: random, grid-layouts, labeling

I would like to assign each vertex a random number with the minimum bound equal to the smallest vertex and the maximum equal to the value of the largest without repeats.

For example, in a 20x20 grid, the vertices would be randomly labeled from 1 to 400 ,without repeats.

Comment: It would be best if you post some code that you have tried so that readers can get a better idea of where your *Mathematica* problem is.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to get random integers

```
Partition[RandomSample[Range[16]], 4]
```

This gets the first 16 integers in random order and formats them in a 4 by 4 block.

[image]

You can change the "16" to 400 and the "4" to 20 and get a larger matrix of such values.

Comment: Might be better to just use `RandomSample[Range[16]]` for the scrambling.

Comment: JM - thanks for the improvement...